# How do I install babelua into Visual Studio?

Tags: babelua

I downloaded babelua. It's a .vsix file. It has the extension icon.
How can I make the extension work with Visual Studio? I keep trying to open the .vsix file and nothing happens.

I REALLY want to work with Lua in visual studio but.. I can't even get Lua to work in it. Please help me get it to work

Babelua site: https://babelua.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version you are using 2012/2013/2015 of visual studio you need to download the correct extension for the version you are using of visual studio. It was not working for me and notice that I downloaded the incorrect version. So go back to the download page and make sure you are trying to install the correct version of babelau for the version of visual studio you plan to use it on.